# Removing blood vessels - denoising the vessels into the background colour

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, image-segmentation, medical

Problem statement:

fundus image, i need to suppress the blood vessels so that they do not appear on the image for the classifier being used.
There were a few thoughts; but easiest approach was to segment out a rough outline of the vasculature. This is achieved.

Next was to get the colour for the surround area and use it to blend it to the white area found; then merge it back to the original image.

Any suggestions for identifying the colour and blending it in. then merging it back to the original image so that the vessels are not visible. One thought was to do a contour of the each white area and find the corresponding colour outside and use it to blend it back.

Any alternate approach is also welcome.

[eyepac image - vessels are visible; want to make it the colour of its surrounding so that they are not visible](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pF9Uc.jpg)

Here is the code:

```
def apply_threshold_with_denoising(image):
    image = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(image, 250, cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C, cv2.THRESH_BINARY, 115, 1)
    image = cv2.fastNlMeansDenoising(image, 1.5, 5, 5)
    return image


def delete_small_components(image, size):
    _, blackAndWhite = cv2.threshold(image, 127, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)
    nlabels, labels, stats, centroids = cv2.connectedComponentsWithStats(blackAndWhite, None, None, None, 8, cv2.CV_32S)
    sizes = stats[1:, -1]  # get CC_STAT_AREA component
    image = np.zeros(labels.shape, np.uint8)

    for i in range(0, nlabels - 1):
        if sizes[i] >= 150:  # filter small dotted regions
            image[labels == i + 1] = 255

    return cv2.bitwise_not(image)


def kernel(num1, num2):
    return np.ones((num1, num2), np.uint8)


def resize(img):
    scale_percent = 50  # percent of original size
    width = int(img.shape[1] * scale_percent / 100)
    height = int(img.shape[0] * scale_percent / 100)
    dim = (width, height)
    # resize image
    return cv2.resize(img, dim, interpolation=cv2.INTER_AREA)


def get_large_vessels(image):
    struct_kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_ELLIPSE, (3, 4))
    opening = cv2.morphologyEx(image, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, struct_kernel, iterations=1)

    cnts = cv2.findContours(opening, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
    cnts = cnts[0] if len(cnts) == 2 else cnts[1]
    for c in cnts:
        area = cv2.contourArea(c)
        if area < 250:
            cv2.drawContours(opening, [c], -1, (0, 0, 0), -1)

    return opening


def get_small_vessels(both, large):
    large = cv2.dilate(large, kernel(3, 3), iterations=5)
    subtract = cv2.subtract(both, large)
    return subtract


def remove_background(image, mask):
    image = cv2.bitwise_and(cv2.bitwise_not(image), cv2.bitwise_not(image), mask=mask)
    image = cv2.morphologyEx(image, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel(2, 2))
    return image


img = cv2.imread('2001_left.jpeg')

hsv = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)

l_b = np.array([0, 0, 30])
u_b = np.array([255, 255, 255])

mask = cv2.inRange(hsv, l_b, u_b)
mask = cv2.erode(mask, kernel(2, 2), iterations=5)

grayscale = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

threshold = apply_threshold_with_denoising(grayscale)

kernel22 = cv2.dilate(threshold, kernel(2, 2), iterations=2)
remove_small1kernel22 = delete_small_components(kernel22, 5)
remove_small1kernel22)

dilation = cv2.dilate(threshold, kernel(2, 1), iterations=2)
remove_small1 = delete_small_components(dilation, 150)

dilation = cv2.dilate(threshold, kernel(1, 2), iterations=2)
remove_small2 = delete_small_components(dilation, 150)

merge = cv2.addWeighted(remove_small1, 0.5, remove_small2, 0.5, 0)
threshold_merge = apply_threshold_with_denoising(merge)


remove_small3 = delete_small_components(threshold_merge, 150)

large_vessels = get_large_vessels(remove_background(remove_small3, mask))
cv2.imshow('Large blood vasculature', large_vessels)


small_vessels = get_small_vessels(remove_background(remove_small3, mask), large_vessels)
cv2.imshow('small vasculature', small_vessels)
```

I tried the above code.

1. It produces the vessels - small and large.
2. I need a way to use this map to recolour using a mean colour value outside each contour such that it blends in when put back.
3. Is there a way to just identify the segment - colour it and then merge back.

Comment: Look up “inpainting”